# FaceBook C# SDK in Windows 8 Release VS2012

Tags: c#, windows, facebook, sdk, microsoft-metro

I downloaded this example about FB SDK C# for metro app at here:
https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-metro-sample

However, when we run it on VS 2012 express + Windows 8 Release Preview, it can't post status to wall after logging is complete.

We get this error message:

> "A first chance exception of type `'System.TypeLoadException'` occurred
>   in Facebook.DLL An exception of type `'System.TypeLoadException'`
>   occurred in Facebook.DLL but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Could not load type `'System.Text.Encoding'` from assembly
>   `'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`."

Does anyone have any idea on how to get this to run with VS2012?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your solution using the source to the SDK itself?   I would assume the problem is the SDK itself and/or your code.  The RunTime Version indicates its not being compiled against .NET 4.5 also.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution ,

download the new version from
https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/tree/565cc5306486bc188771fddebe40861783f2a5b7
(version 6.0.20)

build it in release , and in your project refference the new facebook.dll

It worked for me